# How did Sam know what happened to Boromir?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

Near the end of LOTR: Two Towers when Faramir is close to taking the ring back to Gondor, Sam pleads with Faramir not to take the ring by saying something like this:

> "Do you want to know what happened to Boromir? You want to know why your brother died? He tried to take the Ring from Frodo"

How would Sam know this at all? Earlier in the film it was shown that Frodo didn't even know Boromir had died. Frodo and Boromir were all alone when Boromir tried to take the ring so how could Sam have known Boromir tried to take it and that it led to his death?

Comment: I think the exact quote is "Do you want to know what happened to Boromir? You want to know why your brother died? He tried to take the Ring from Frodo!" Sam probably knew Boromir lost his mind because Frodo told him.

Comment: The "tried to take it part" is easy: Frodo told Sam (who doesn't care for reasons in the heat of the moment of the don't-you-leave-him scene, but will probably be curious afterwards why Frodo had decided to go all alone) off-screen.

Answer (score 10):

Within the novel, Faramir tells Frodo and Sam that Boromir has died, and they fill in the gaps around what happened prior to that.

> Faramir smiled grimly. ‘Then you would grieve to learn that Boromir is dead?’

They work out that the days match up so that Faramir's vision is from the same day as they left.

> ‘But the day when you heard it blowing, if your reckoning is true, was the day when we parted, when I and my servant left the Company.

Comment: Faramir tells them first in the film as well. Sam is then likely supposing that Boromir's attack on Frodo precipitated his [ Boromir's] death - https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-The-Two-Towers.html

Comment: +1 because I think it gets at the answer, but weren't the uruk-hai already after them? It hardly seems that obvious to me that him trying to take the ring is the reason he dies. Seems to me that the reason he dies is because a bunch of uruk-hai attack him. The most you could say is that there wasn't anyone around Boromir to defend him at the exact moment of attack, but that's a pretty circumstantial detail. How did Sam conclude that this was how it happened, and that the ring was the cause? Or am I forgetting something?

Comment: Sam is loyal to Frodo, perhaps beyond the point of common sense. The novel (read many more times than I have seen the movie!) doesn't have either Hobbit state why he died - they are clear he was alive when they left. In the movie it's not clear if Sam believes Boromir trying to take the ring led to his death, or if he's intentionally exaggerating his knowledge to try to persuade Faramir to release them.

Comment: As Boromir was already known as a very capable warrior, and literally the entire rest of the fellowship survives, they may be assuming that Boromir's ability should have been enough that he wouldn't have died unless otherwise handicapped. Since the timing adds up, it makes sense that the ring's pull was that handicap...

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle Well, except Sam had no way of knowing that the rest of the fellowship survived - not to mention that they survived barely, and Merry and Pippin got captured.  Frodo and Sam would have likely gotten captured too, if Boromir hadn't scared Frodo away.  As for the ring's *pull*, I'm not sure what about it handicapped Boromir.  Other than being alone in the woods when the Uruk-hai attacked, there's no reason to think he fought worse for it.  Tolkien does have a habit of giving his main characters God mode, but Sam doesn't know that.  I mean it's a horde of Uruk-hai.